# Updating a 3 year old iOS app to conform to the latest Apple requirements

Tags: ios, applications

I contracted an app to be developed and which was released a few years ago.  According to the developers, apparently Apple has updated the coding requirements and the developers are saying the app needs to be recoded in order to remain viable and that perhaps 300 hours or more would be required.  The difficulty is said to derive from "Cordoba" being used as a framework for the original development. (I am not a developer or coder)

Is it true that this is not a daunting task and that recompiling with the latest iterations of Swift/X-Code is possible and requires little effort?

Many thanks for any help with this question.

Answer (score 1):

The coder most probably meant Cordova, and not Cordoba. The latter does not exist, but [Apache Cordova](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Cordova) is a relatively popular app development framework.

From your question I get the impression that you think the original app developers are lying to you, or are incompetent, and they're taking a 2 hour job and quoting it at 300 hours. If that is the case, you have lost trust in your developers and that never ends well.

It is completely impossible for anyone here to judge whether this is a 300 hour, 150 hour or 5 hour job, with the information given in the question. Consider going to your developer and ask them why this task is a 300 hour job - they should be able to provide you with a description of what needs to be done.

If you have lost trust in your developers, I would suggest getting a quote from a different developer. Note that you risk that they qoute you low, and end up spending just as much time as the others would have done.